# Why do protestants accept Augustine's teachings?

Tags: protestantism, virgin-mary, church-fathers

St Augustine seemed to believe in the catholic doctrine of [Mediatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediatrix), infant baptism and purgatory:

> "May the sins we bring before Almighty God through thee, become pardonable through thee; may what we ask for with sure confidence, through thee be granted."
>
> "Through thee we hope for the remission of our sins, and in thee, O blessed Lady, is our hope of reward."
> *Prayer of Saint Augustine to the Blessed Virgin* [learnreligions.com](https://www.learnreligions.com/prayer-of-saint-augustine-blessed-virgin-542613)

Why do Protestant theologians who don't hold these views, accept his teachings for their reference?

Comment: You seem to be asking/asserting at least three things here: How Protestants excuse Augustine's worship of Mary, why Jesus would warn churches of elect people, and that salvation is for all not just the chosen (not even a question, just an bald assertion). All of these are things you can ask about on this site, but you can't do so in just one question like this.

Comment: I ask it in goodwill to reason/understand(1 Peter 3:15 & Acts 17:17); so please share your insights. Please let me know how my concern is not focused, as I have just added details to my question _Why is Augustine of Hippo's teachings considered by Protestants?_

Comment: @AshishEben Sorry the site can seem unwelcoming to new users. Please take a moment read the [help](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) on how it is different. Basically this unlike online discussion forums this is a Q&A site. The questions should be written objectively and focus on a single topic. The answers should not contain personal opinion but reference Church leaders or literature to show that it is a widely held belief/position.

Comment: In regards to improving your question, it should not contain an exhaustive explanation of why Marian worship is wrong. All protestants already know and agree with that. A short statement like "Why do protestants who reject mary worship, accept Augustine as Church father?" should be sufficient. I'll propose an edit to your question.

Comment: **@JohnDoe** Augustine (RC) even believed/supported infant baptism & purgatory. John Calvin (Protestant) too was inspired by Augustine's teachings on infant baptism. So just to add details to my question, can I mention that too in **your proposed edit**.

Comment: You should remove the misattributed prayer to Mary, since it's not Augustine's but Bishop Fulberts from the 11th century.(the misattribution probably arose because some manuscripts contain random addendum works because of the preciousness of paper/ink etc.). Augustine did pray to the saints, including Mary, but this isn't his prayer. Also, it's highly disrespectful to call veneration of the mother of God, a blessed human being, "worship." Worship is given to God, whereas not even heretics of any sect believe Mary to be God or worthy of the worship of God.

Comment: **@SolaGratia** So what about Augustine's teachings/beliefs which supported infant baptism & purgatory. Please even share reference for the misattributed/misquoted part, as its not traceable; however [here](https://d2y1pz2y630308.cloudfront.net/11413/documents/2021/3/Via%20Crucis%20-%20A%20Marian%20Set%20of%20Meditation.pdf) found out that Bishop Fulbert had a different prayer towards Mary and isn't identical to Augustine's, as the pdf even mentions Augustine's prayer to Mary (as quoted in the query).

Comment: @AshishEben Again you're missing the point. This site is not a discussion forum. Questions like these are not allowed because they don't yield answers they yield never ending debate. Just look at your comment, your initial question was about praying to Mary, and now you are talking about infant baptism & purgatory.

Comment: @AshishEben *Please even share reference for the misattributed/misquoted part*. If you want that you can ask a question specifically focused on this, something like. "Is this Prayer correctly attributed to St Augustine?"

Comment: @AshishEben In your question you've mentioned *God's salvation is for all who believes in the Gospel of Jesus Christ, not just for the chosen.* This is not related in anyway to the doctrine of Mediatrix. All can pray to Mary just as all can pray to Christ? So the bottom line is your question is too long, and all over the place. Break it up into multiple questions, with each focused on a single narrow topic.

Comment: **@JohnDoe** It seems there you are misinterpreting my overall query, my concern is despite the fallacy of Augustine's beliefs in mediatrix, infant baptism & purgatory, his teachings are still considered like on predestination which inspired John Calvin. However thanks for highlighting

Comment: @AshishEben I'd simply say. Protestants generally tend to discern the sayings of Church Fathers. Luther said in the Bondage of the Will: " The authority of the fathers, 
therefore, is to be accounted nought: and those statutes which have been wrongly enacted, (as all 
have been that are not according to the Word of God) are to be rent in sunder and cast away", in light of 1 John 4. In other Words, the Fathers can have both good and not so genius writings, just like anyone else, we discern based of Scripture.

Comment: **@Dan** Perfect, that's the case and we need to thread carefully, like in the case of Martin Luther & John Calvin both were anti-Semitic which isn't scriptural. So we need to examine the doctrine/theology/interpretation like the Bereans